# How to get X/Y corrdinates with jquerymobile all the time my finger is moving? Like mousemove for Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm writing code for a colorpicker, especially for mobile devices.

This code is working on my Desktop, where the color is refreshed as long the mouse is moving ("mousemove"), how can i achieve the same with a mobile event? Tap or something is just fired once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on Windows Firefox, Android Jellybean 4.1 and iPad.
jQuery Mobile code:

```
$('#index').on('touchstart vmousedown', function(){
    $('#startend').text('Touch start');
})

$('#index').on('touchmove vmousemove', function(event){
    $('#move-x').text(event.pageX);
    $('#move-y').text(event.pageY);
})

$('#index').on('touchend vmouseup', function(){
    $('#startend').text('Touch end');
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="index">
    //content here
</div>
<span id="move-x"></span>
<span id="move-y"></span>
<span id="startend"></span>
```

Comment: Okay thank you, "live" was removed with jquery 1.9, but its working with "on" too :)